# Joining multiple tables to display entire data without cross joining

Tags: sql-server, join

First, my apologies for not having a somewhat vague Title of my question.

I will try to explain in detail here.

I am trying to join more than 4 tables. Each of them has structure_id as the column amongst them.

The tables along with their names are shown below;

Structure Table:

| Structure ID | Name | No. of Spans |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 |
| 7 | Kimlog | 3 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 |
| 9 | Loops | 6 |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 |

Span Bearing Table:

| Structure ID | BSpan No. |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | (null) |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 10 | 5 |

Span Table:

| Structure ID | Span No. |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 9 | 6 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 10 | 5 |

Substructure Table:

| Structure ID | Element No. |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 85 |
| 8 | 86 |
| 8 | 87 |
| 8 | 88 |
| 8 | 89 |
| 8 | 90 |
| 9 | (null) |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 10 | 6 |

The SQL query to create and insert the data is below;

```
CREATE TABLE structures (structure_id INT, name VARCHAR(20), no_of_spans INT);
CREATE TABLE span_bearing (structure_id INT, B_Span_no INT);
CREATE TABLE span (structure_id INT, Span_no INT);
CREATE TABLE substructure (structure_id INT, Structure_element_no INT);

INSERT INTO structures (structure_id,name,no_of_spans) VALUES(5,"Fraser",4);
INSERT INTO structures (structure_id,name,no_of_spans) VALUES(6,"Chiloctin",6);
INSERT INTO structures (structure_id,name,no_of_spans) VALUES(7,"Kimlog",3);
INSERT INTO structures (structure_id,name,no_of_spans) VALUES(8,"Burley",5);
INSERT INTO structures (structure_id,name,no_of_spans) VALUES(9,"Loops",6);
INSERT INTO structures (structure_id,name,no_of_spans) VALUES(10,"Lupin",5);

INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(5,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,5);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,5);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,6);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(6,6);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(7,NULL);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,5);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(8,5);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(9,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,1);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,2);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,3);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,4);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,5);
INSERT INTO span_bearing (structure_id,B_Span_no) VALUES(10,5);

INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(5,2);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(5,3);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(5,4);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(6,1);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(6,2);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(6,3);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(6,4);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(6,5);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(6,6);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(7,1);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(7,2);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(7,3);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(8,1);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(8,2);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(8,3);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(8,4);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(8,5);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(9,1);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(9,2);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(9,3);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(9,4);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(9,5);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(9,6);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(10,1);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(10,2);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(10,3);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(10,4);
INSERT INTO span (structure_id,Span_no) VALUES(10,5);

INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(5,2);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(5,3);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(5,4);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(5,5);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(6,1);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(6,2);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(6,3);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(6,4);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(7,1);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(7,2);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(7,3);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(7,4);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(8,85);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(8,86);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(8,87);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(8,88);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(8,89);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(8,90);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(9,NULL);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(10,1);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(10,2);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(10,3);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(10,4);
INSERT INTO substructure (structure_id,Structure_element_no) VALUES(10,5);
```

***The result that I want is:***

| Structure ID | Name | No. of Spans | BSpan_no | Span_no | Element No. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 3 |  | 5 |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 3 |  |  |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 4 |  |  |
| 5 | Fraser | 4 | 4 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 2 | 5 |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 3 | 6 |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 3 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 4 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 4 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 4 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 5 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 5 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 6 |  |  |
| 6 | Chiloctin | 6 | 6 |  |  |
| 7 | Kimlog | 3 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | Kimlog | 3 |  | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | Kimlog | 3 |  | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | Kimlog | 3 |  |  | 4 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 1 | 1 | 85 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 1 | 2 | 86 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 2 | 3 | 87 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 2 | 4 | 88 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 3 | 5 | 89 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 3 |  | 90 |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 4 |  |  |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 4 |  |  |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 5 |  |  |
| 8 | Burley | 5 | 5 |  |  |
| 9 | Loops | 6 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | Loops | 6 |  | 2 |  |
| 9 | Loops | 6 |  | 3 |  |
| 9 | Loops | 6 |  | 4 |  |
| 9 | Loops | 6 |  | 5 |  |
| 9 | Loops | 6 |  | 6 |  |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 3 |  | 6 |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 4 |  |  |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 4 |  |  |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 5 |  |  |
| 10 | Lupin | 5 | 5 |  |  |

You can see from the tables that there is some kind of a Data mismatch for some Structures i.e. information of a particular structure is available in one table but its corresponding data is either partially available or completely unavailable in other tables.

This really has caused lot of issues as I am dealing with over 8000 structures.

I have, to a greater extent, achieved the desired output by using UNION ALL. But my code has become too long (i.e. over 3000 lines) and too repetitive. But still there are structures that are not displaying complete information.

Below is the sample of my query that I used:

```
SELECT 
   
    STR_ID,
    NAME,
    No_of_Spans
    SUBSTRUCTURE_ELEMENT_NO,
    BSpan_no,
    Span_no,
    
    ID_1
    
FROM 

(

WITH span AS (
        
        SELECT STRUCTURE_ID,span_no,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STRUCTURE_ID ORDER BY STRUCTURE_ID) Span_ID
        FROM span

            )
SELECT 
     
    STR_ID,
    NAME,
    No_of_Spans
    SUBSTRUCTURE_ELEMENT_NO,
    BSpan_no, 
    span.span_no,
    Span_Brng
    ID_1

FROM (

WITH subs AS (
        
        SELECT STRUCTURE_ID,SUBSTRUCTURE_ELEMENT_NO,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STRUCTURE_ID ORDER BY SUBSTRUCTURE_ELEMENT_NO) Subs_ID
           FROM substructure         
)

SELECT 
    
    STR_ID,
    NAME,
    No_of_Spans
    subs.SUBSTRUCTURE_ELEMENT_NO,
    BSpan_no,
    span_no_1,
    
    Span_Brng,
    ID_1
    
FROM (

SELECT 
    
    
    STR_ID,
    NAME,
    No_of_Spans
    BSpan_no, 
    Span_Brng
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STR_ID ORDER BY STR_ID) ID_1 


FROM (


WITH bspan AS ( 
                SELECT STRUCTURE_ID,BSPAN_NO,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY structure_ID ORDER BY structure_ID) Span_Brng
                FROM span_bearing
            )
SELECT 
    

    STR_ID,
    NAME,
    No_of_Spans
       
    bspan.bspan_no,
    bspan.Span_Brng


    

FROM 
                            
    STRUCTURE a    
    LEFT JOIN rs1 ON a.structure_id=rs1.structure_id, 
      
)

)tbl1 

LEFT JOIN rs2 ON  tbl1.STR_ID = rs2.STRUCTURE_ID AND tbl1.ID_1 = rs2.Subs_ID


) tbl2

LEFT JOIN rs3 ON tbl2.Str_ID = rs3.structure_id AND tbl2.ID_1=rs3.span_id

WHERE tbl2.bspan_no IS NOT NULL
```

The above SQL query is only a sample of my entire code. It is greatly simplified.

In my code, the last line i.e. ***WHERE tbl2.bspan_no IS NOT NULL*** had to be used.
If it is not used, then the result I get is:

[image]

So many structures have data issues. I cannot keep using UNION ALL to accommodate those structures.

1. Please inform me is it because of LEFT JOINS that the issue arises?
2. Is there any alternative to UNION ALL?
3. Is there any way I can join multiple tables where every data from any table is fully displayed without CROSS JOINING?

Your support, as it has always been, would be greatly appreciated.

Once again I apologize if I couldn't explain my question properly. If you want more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the trick to something like this, is to make a fake 'row number' for each value that represents which row it will be reported on (for the given structure).

The easiest way to do this

- For the structure table, just cross join it with a 'numbers' table (making as many rows as you could possibly need)
- For the other tables (spans etc), use the ROW_NUMBER function to order them and provide the relevant row

Therefore, for each table, it will fundamentally have a two-part 'key'

- Structure_ID
- The row number for that structure

The below code does that in the CTEs, and then simply LEFT JOINS the other tables to the structure table

Code/example available at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FJJTf_Sw)

Notes

- Edit: This previously used temporary tables, but are now the original names. The db<>fiddle uses temporary tables currently.
- The 'Nums' table (which has 1, 2, 3, ...) is currently limited to 40. This should be as big or bigger as the most number of rows you'll need for any single structure.

  - Edit: Because of OP's issue with cross-joined VALUES, the Nums table logic has been replaced with a SELECT ROW_NUMBER
- The output below includes the row number (Nums.n) for illustrative purposes. Feel free to remove this in use.

```
WITH    SP_B AS (SELECT structure_id,B_Span_no, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY structure_id ORDER BY B_Span_no) AS rn 
                FROM span_bearing),
        SP AS   (SELECT structure_id,Span_no, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY structure_id ORDER BY Span_no) AS rn 
                FROM span),
        SubS AS (SELECT structure_id,Structure_element_no, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY structure_id ORDER BY Structure_element_no) AS rn 
                FROM substructure),
        Nums AS (SELECT TOP 40 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i) AS n FROM
                    (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) AS A
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS j UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) AS B
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS k UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) AS C
                )
        -- Nums AS (SELECT 1 + (Digits.n) + (Tens.n * 10) AS n 
        --        FROM    (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS Digits(n) 
        --                CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) AS Tens(n))
    SELECT      structures.structure_id,
                Nums.n,
                structures.name,
                Structures.no_of_spans,
                SP_B.B_Span_no,
                SP.Span_no,
                SubS.Structure_element_no
        FROM    structures
                CROSS JOIN Nums
                LEFT OUTER JOIN SP_B ON structures.structure_id = SP_B.structure_id AND Nums.n = SP_B.rn
                LEFT OUTER JOIN SP   ON structures.structure_id = SP.structure_id   AND Nums.n = SP.rn
                LEFT OUTER JOIN SubS ON structures.structure_id = SubS.structure_id AND Nums.n = SubS.rn
        WHERE   SP_B.B_Span_no IS NOT NULL
                OR SP.Span_no IS NOT NULL
                OR SubS.Structure_element_no IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY structures.structure_id, Nums.n;
```

Results - noting expected results for 7 (Kimlog)

```
structure_id n           name                 no_of_spans B_Span_no   Span_no     Structure_element_no
------------ ----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
5            1           Fraser               4           1           1           1
5            2           Fraser               4           1           2           2
5            3           Fraser               4           2           3           3
5            4           Fraser               4           2           4           4
5            5           Fraser               4           3           NULL        5
5            6           Fraser               4           3           NULL        NULL
5            7           Fraser               4           4           NULL        NULL
5            8           Fraser               4           4           NULL        NULL
6            1           Chiloctin            6           1           1           1
6            2           Chiloctin            6           1           2           2
6            3           Chiloctin            6           1           3           3
6            4           Chiloctin            6           2           4           4
6            5           Chiloctin            6           2           5           NULL
6            6           Chiloctin            6           3           6           NULL
6            7           Chiloctin            6           3           NULL        NULL
6            8           Chiloctin            6           4           NULL        NULL
6            9           Chiloctin            6           4           NULL        NULL
6            10          Chiloctin            6           4           NULL        NULL
6            11          Chiloctin            6           5           NULL        NULL
6            12          Chiloctin            6           5           NULL        NULL
6            13          Chiloctin            6           6           NULL        NULL
6            14          Chiloctin            6           6           NULL        NULL
7            1           Kimlog               3           NULL        1           1
7            2           Kimlog               3           NULL        2           2
7            3           Kimlog               3           NULL        3           3
7            4           Kimlog               3           NULL        NULL        4
8            1           Burley               5           1           1           85
8            2           Burley               5           1           2           86
8            3           Burley               5           2           3           87
8            4           Burley               5           2           4           88
8            5           Burley               5           3           5           89
8            6           Burley               5           3           NULL        90
8            7           Burley               5           4           NULL        NULL
8            8           Burley               5           4           NULL        NULL
8            9           Burley               5           5           NULL        NULL
8            10          Burley               5           5           NULL        NULL
9            1           Loops                6           1           1           NULL
9            2           Loops                6           NULL        2           NULL
9            3           Loops                6           NULL        3           NULL
9            4           Loops                6           NULL        4           NULL
9            5           Loops                6           NULL        5           NULL
9            6           Loops                6           NULL        6           NULL
10           1           Lupin                5           1           1           1
10           2           Lupin                5           1           2           2
10           3           Lupin                5           2           3           3
10           4           Lupin                5           2           4           4
10           5           Lupin                5           3           5           5
10           6           Lupin                5           3           NULL        NULL
10           7           Lupin                5           4           NULL        NULL
10           8           Lupin                5           4           NULL        NULL
10           9           Lupin                5           5           NULL        NULL
10           10          Lupin                5           5           NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Thanks so much dear seanb. This definitely has given me a new way of solving problems like these. The only issue I am having right now is SQL-Server (i think!!).  At the line " FROM    (VALUES (0), (1), ..." it gives an error 'invalid table name'.  The other issue on top of it is that I cannot create any new table nor modify the existing ones in the database.

Comment: Hi @ar - I have modified my response in two ways. 1) Removed the temp tables and used their original names (no new tables etc are created here - I was just using temp tables for testing). 2) Changed the way the Nums table was generated. Note that these changes haven't changed the results though.  However, the fact you have values with double quotes e.g., `VALUES(5,"Fraser",4);`, and there are issues with that VALUES approach for generating numbers, suggests this isn't SQL Server but is something else? There may be better ways in that database to create the virtual Nums table.

Comment: Dear seanb. Your code has worked. I just did a slight adjustment and it has worked wonders for me. My code has got significantly shortened. Can't thank you enough for giving me a new way of dealing with projects like these. I can now join as many tables as I like by incorporating your technique. A big Thanks to you once again.